# WQHD Monitor connected to the laptop

Tags: laptop, hdmi

I'd like to buy a WQHD monitor which would serve as an external monitor for my laptop. I have HP DV6 series laptop: http://tinyurl.com/khjnq3x and i as far i can tell monitor would need to be connected with at least HDMI 1.3 cable to be able to run at 2560x1440 resolution. My only concern is if my laptop supports all versions of HDMI.

Is there any way to check if my laptop can run with external monitor at 2560x1440 without actually buy it first?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: That laptop doesn't even seem to have an HDMI port?

Comment: @ernie It has to be mistake on HP's side. My laptop has HDMI port. I've been using it to connect external monitors to my laptop but all of them were FHD.